# Integral 0f a function with range in convex set is in the convex set

Tags: real-analysis

The question is: Consider the set $X$ with measure $\sigma(X)=1$. Let $K$ be a compact convex subset of $\mathbb{C}$. Let $f$ be a complex valued, measurable function defined on $X$ such that the range of $f$ is in $K$. Show that $f$ is integrable w.r.t. $\sigma$ and that
$$
\int_X f(x)\sigma(dx) \in K
$$
What have I done so far: I was able to show that $f$ is integrable w.r.t. to $\sigma$. However, I am having a lot of grief showing that the integral is in the compact convex set. I can see that this is true for a small non-trivial case like say a unit square with the four corners having the value $\frac14$ but this is proving to be beyond me. I have consulted Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis and Folland's Real Analysis but to no avail. It seems like this might be a theorem of a corollary of a theorem and I am missing a link. Any suggestions?

Comment: Anyone? Anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An informal argument is that, since the values of $f$ are in $K$ a compact convex subset of $\mathbb{C}$ and $\int_X f(x)\sigma (dx)$ is an average of the values of $f$, then this average exists (since $f$ is finite) and must belong to $K$.

---

Now I will show a formal proof. In this proof, I will assume you are familiar with [Hahn-Banach separation theorem I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane_separation_theorem)

By contradiction, assume $z_0=\int_X f(x)\sigma (dx)\notin K$. Using $K$ and $\{z_0\}$ are compact convex disjoint sets, by Hahn-Banach separation theorem, there exists $v\in \mathbb{C}$ and $d\in\mathbb{R}$, s.t. 
$$
\langle v,z\rangle < d < \langle v,z_0\rangle
$$ 
for all $z\in K$. Then 
$$
\langle v,f(x)\rangle < d < \langle v,z_0\rangle
$$
for all $x\in X$.

Let $g:X\to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $g(x)=\langle v,f(x)\rangle$. We can show $g$ is a measurable and integrable function, using $f$ measurable and integrable.

On the one hand, we can show
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_X g(x)\sigma (dx) dx & = &\int_X \langle v,f(x)\rangle\sigma(dx)\\
& = & \langle v,\int_X f(x)\sigma(dx)\rangle\\
& = & \langle v,z_0\rangle
\end{eqnarray}
while on the other hand, 
$$
\langle v,z_0\rangle=\int_X g(x)\sigma (dx) dx<d<\langle v,z_0\rangle
$$
which is a contradiction.

Comment: Aha! The Hahn-Banach Sep Thm 1 is the key. Thank you so, so much!

Comment: You are welcome. Glad you found my answer useful.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach can based on the distance-to-the-boundary  function. As a bonus, $K$ need only be convex and bounded. (For unbounded $K$, one must assume that $\int|f(x)|\,\sigma(dx)<\infty$.) Define $\varphi(z)=\inf\{|z-w|:w\in\partial K\}$ (the distance to the boundary $\partial K$ of $K$) for $z\in K$ and $\varphi(z)=-\infty$ for $z\notin K$. Then $\varphi:\Bbb C\to[-\infty,\infty)$ is concave. Let $m$ denote $\int_X f(x)\,\sigma(dx)$. By the vector-valued form of Jensen's inequality,
$$
\varphi(m)\ge\int_X \varphi(f(x))\,\sigma(dx)\ge 0,
$$
the final inequality following because $f$ takes values in $K$ and $\varphi(z)\ge 0$ for all $z\in K$. It follows that $\varphi(m)\ge 0$; in particular, $\varphi(m)>-\infty$, so $m\in K$.

This argument works in all dimensions, and more generally in topological vector spaces for which (i) barycenters of probability measures exist and (ii) an appropriate form of Jensen's inequality holds.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative route, John.

Comment: This is a perfect example of a flawed proof. Jensen's inequality is generally stated for proper, that is real-valued, convex functions. If you want to extend it to convex functions $\varphi$ taking values in $(-\infty,\infty]$, then it amounts to prove that if $\int \varphi \circ f d\mu$ is finite (so that f takes a.e. values in the effective domain of $\varphi$), then $\int f d \mu$ is in the effective domain of $\varphi$, which is what we want to prove! PS For the definition of effective domain of a convex function, see e.g. Rockafellar, Convex Analysis.

Comment: Nate River's proof works well, and for another proof you can see e.g. Dudley, Real Analysis and Probability, Theorem (10.2.6).

Comment: Anyhow, I want to thank John Dawkins for making me know this wonderful proof: the distance function $f(x)=d(x,\partial C)$ from the boundary of an open convex set $C \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a concave function on $C$. For a proof, see e.g. Güler, Foundations of Optimization, Theorem (6.20) or Hörmander, Notions of Convexity, Theorem (2.1.24). In the case $n=2$, you can prove the Theorem in a pure geometric way. Take two points $x, y \in C$, and draw the open discs $D_x$ and $D_y$ with centers $x$ and $y$ and radii $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ respectively.

Comment: Then, for every $t \in (0,1)$ the open disc with center $tx+(1-t)y$ and radius $tf(x) +(1-t)f(y)$ is contained in the convex hull of $D_x$ and $D_y$, and so in $C$. QED

Comment: @MaurizioBarbato: Indeed, my use of that form of Jensen does beg the question.